# Change macrocode environment colour when documenting package with ltxdoc

Tags: dtx

Need help in customising class `ltxdoc`.
I would like to colour code `macrocode` environments so as to facilitate the visual distinction between package's macro code and it associated documentation.

I tried to create a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{sourcecode}%
{\color{blue}\begin{macrocode}}%
{\end{macrocode}}
```

That failed with a *capacity size exceeded* (set for the occasion to `100000`).

I had a look at `ltxdoc.dtx` to see if I could simply import the `macrocode` environment. But its implementation is too cryptic for me.

Thanks for any insight here :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the environment hooks from the package `etoolbox` in the first part of the `.dtx`.

MWE:

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{macrocode}{\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{dtxcolor.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \StopEventually{}
%
%This is a description of the code below.
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \mathchardef\implies="3221 \mathchardef\impliedby="3220 \mathchardef\Implies=%
"3229 \mathchardef\Impliedby="3228 \mathchardef\implic="2221 \mathchardef
\implicby="2220 \mathchardef\Implic="2229 \mathchardef\Implicby="2228 \let
\imp\to%%
%    \end{macrocode}
% \Finale
\endinput
```

Result (with `latex dtxcolor.dtx`):

[image]

Comment: When the `macrocode` environment is immediately preceded by with a `\DescribeMacro{mymacro}`, the `mymacro` in the margin gets coloured too. Adding some documentation text between `\DescribeMacro{mymacro}` and `\begin{macrocode}` resolves the colour issue.

Comment: @JM.Marcastel you might be able to patch `DescribeMacro` as well (with `pretocmd` etc.), for example put `\color{black}` in front and `\color{blue}` at the end.