# A different font for macro code in ltxdoc,

Tags: fonts

I use ltxdoc and want to have a different font for the macro code.
Inspired by

[Change macrocode environment colour when documenting package with ltxdoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404639/change-macrocode-environment-colour-when-documenting-package-with-ltxdoc)

I tried the suggestion given there

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{macrocode}{Xx\huge\bfseries Yy}
```

Now the Yy is in huge/bold, but the rest of the macros is not.
Any hint to what I should do?

Comment: your question would (as always) be clearer if you showed as test document, but in principle you just need to define `\MacroFont` to be whatever font you want, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

`macrocode` uses the hook `\MacroFont` which you can define to be whatever:

```
%\iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{color}
\renewcommand\MacroFont{\Huge\color{blue}\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

\DocInput{\jobname}
\end{document}

%\fi


%some stuff that does something
%    \begin{macrocode}
\zz
\zzzzz
\zzZ
%    \end{macrocode}
```

Comment: Thank you David.
I did not find something like MacroFont in the ltxdoc documentation, but 
after searching for it I found it in doc.sty. The doc.sty documentation 
gives me some further clues

Comment: ltxdoc` is a very thin wrapper that just loads `doc` package with `article` class and a few helper commands for documenting the base latex sources, all the real code is in the doc package.

Comment: Yes, you made me aware of that. Thanks again